# Meta_query in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to use the meta_query in WooCommerce product page.

This is the code I'm using:

```
  <?php
  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' =>8,
      'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'autor',
                'value' => '"'.get_the_ID().'"',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
      ),
  );
  $products = new WP_Query($args);
  if ($products->have_posts()) :
      $i=0;
      while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post();
          $autor = get_field('autor');
          if($i % 2 ==0) ?>


                    <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>

  <?php  if ($i % 2 != 0)
  $i++;
  endwhile;endif;?>
```

It doesn't show any title, if I remove the meta_query it shows all products so the problem is that the relation meta_query code is not working. Any ideas how to use it on WooCommerce template?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the relationship you are trying to query?

Answer (score 0):

You use `get_the_ID()` to get the author id in meta_query args.

`get_the_ID()` - will get the Post id, not the author id.

To get all posts by authoк id your args should look like this:

```
$args = array(
        'author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
);
```

I also see that you using `get_field()`-function. WordPress core does not have this function. You can use instead `get_the_author()`.

Eventually your code will look like:

```
<?php
$args = array(
        'author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);

if ($products->have_posts()) :
        $i=0;
        while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post();
                $autor = get_the_author();
                if($i % 2 ==0) ?>
                                    <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>

<?php  if ($i % 2 != 0)
$i++;
endwhile;endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this code snippet for meta_query in woocommerce

$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=> 10,
    'orderby'       => 'total_sales',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'  => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => '_featured',
            'value'     => 'yes',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'total_sales',
            'value'     => '10',
            'compare'   => '>='
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```